# Airflow - Compute Engine SSH Hook creates a new pair of keys everytime it connects to VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, ssh-keys, google-cloud-composer

We have Airflow 2.5.3 running on GCP Cloud Composer (2.4.6). Around 200 tasks need to be daily executed on a VM located on the same project and VPC. Thus, we need to use an SSHOperator to execute the scripts on the VM.

To start, we created new ssh keys on the VM and loaded the private key on the Composer's GCS bucket. However, when we ran the SSHOperator on Airflow, every time it ran it generated a new set of keys (!)

We tried running different configurations for it, but kept bumping into the same result. Even worse, when parallel tasks were executed, the DAG stalled waiting for new keys. We are worried that when we launch this into production, we will generate an ever increasing amount of ssh keys.

Is there a way to force the SSHOperator to use the previously generated keys? Or to use only one set?
Is there something wrong with our approach?
Even though it ultimately works, I think it is still pretty nasty.

Here is the code and log.

```
hook1 = ComputeEngineSSHHook(
        instance_name=GCE_INSTANCE,
        zone=GCE_ZONE,
        project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
        user=GCE_USER,
        use_oslogin=False,
        use_iap_tunnel=True,
        use_internal_ip=True,
        key_file='/home/airflow/gcs/sshkey'
    )
hook2 = ComputeEngineSSHHook(
        instance_name=GCE_INSTANCE,
        zone=GCE_ZONE,
        project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
        user=GCE_USER,
        use_oslogin=False,
        use_iap_tunnel=True,
        use_internal_ip=True
    )

test1 = SSHOperator(
    task_id='test1',
    ssh_hook=hook1,
    command='ls -l',
    conn_timeout=120,
    cmd_timeout=120,
    dag=dag
    )

test2 = SSHOperator(
    task_id='test2',
    ssh_hook=hook2,
    command='ls -l',
    conn_timeout=120,
    cmd_timeout=120,
    dag=dag
    )
```

The result is the same for both tests. Here is an example:

```
[2023-10-31, 13:10:20 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1310} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): test2> on 2023-10-31 12:05:00+00:00
[2023-10-31, 13:10:20 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 197372 to run task
[2023-10-31, 13:10:20 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test', 'test2', 'scheduled__2023-10-31T12:05:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1366', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpt4ykt_sw']
[2023-10-31, 13:10:20 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 1366: Subtask test2
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {task_command.py:393} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test.test2 scheduled__2023-10-31T12:05:00+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-kwpxv
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1518} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=test2
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-10-31T12:05:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-10-31T12:05:00+00:00
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {ssh.py:135} INFO - Creating ssh_client
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {compute_ssh.py:213} INFO - Connecting to instance: instance_name=<<GCE_INSTANCE>>, user=<<GCE_USER>>, zone=<<GCE_ZONE>>, use_internal_ip=True, use_iap_tunnel=True, use_os_login=False
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2023-10-31, 13:10:21 UTC] {compute_ssh.py:339} INFO - Generating ssh keys...
[2023-10-31, 13:10:22 UTC] {compute_ssh.py:303} INFO - Appending SSH public key to instance metadata
[2023-10-31, 13:10:22 UTC] {compute.py:750} INFO - Waiting for Operation to complete...
[2023-10-31, 13:10:23 UTC] {compute.py:750} INFO - Waiting for Operation to complete...
[2023-10-31, 13:10:24 UTC] {compute.py:750} INFO - Waiting for Operation to complete...
[2023-10-31, 13:10:25 UTC] {compute.py:750} INFO - Waiting for Operation to complete...
[2023-10-31, 13:10:25 UTC] {compute_ssh.py:279} INFO - Opening remote connection to host: username=<<GCE_USER>>, hostname=<<GCE_INTERNAL IP>>
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1893} ERROR - Exception (client): ProxyCommand("gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel <<GCE_INSTANCE>> 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=<<GCE_PROJECT_ID>> --zone=<<GCE_ZONE>> --verbosity=warning") returned nonzero exit status: Broken pipe
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 79, in send
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -     self.process.stdin.write(content)
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - 
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - 
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2108, in run
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -     self.packetizer.write_all(b(self.local_version + "\r\n"))
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 333, in write_all
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -     n = self.__socket.send(out)
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 85, in send
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR -     raise ProxyCommandFailure(" ".join(self.cmd), e.strerror)
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ProxyCommand("gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel <<GCE_INSTANCE>> 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=<<GCE_PROJECT_ID>> --zone=<<GCE_ZONE>> --verbosity=warning") returned nonzero exit status: Broken pipe
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {transport.py:1891} ERROR - 
[2023-10-31, 13:10:29 UTC] {compute_ssh.py:298} INFO - Failed to connect. Waiting 0s to retry
[2023-10-31, 13:10:32 UTC] {transport.py:1893} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.0)
[2023-10-31, 13:10:32 UTC] {transport.py:1893} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
[2023-10-31, 13:10:32 UTC] {ssh.py:476} INFO - Running command: ls -l
[2023-10-31, 13:10:32 UTC] {ssh.py:522} INFO - total 1780608

<<SUCCESS: IT THEN LISTS ALL THE FILES>>
```

We also tried changing parameters such as `use_oslogin=True` but kept bumping into the same wall.

Comment: In case anyone is stalled by this error, I found a workaround that keeps Airflow from generating new keys here: https://groups.google.com/g/cloud-composer-discuss/c/XsYtksRlHpc It is annoying but it works